# Умножение элементов двумерного массива на число

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Как работает с одномерным массивом, понятно:

```
lst = [1,3,5,7]
n = 3
c = list(map(lambda x: x*n, lst))
c
[3, 9, 15, 21]
```

Как сделать тоже самое с двумерным массивом?

Используя тот же способ, получаю:

```
lst = [[2,3,4,5,5],[1,3]]
n = 2
c = list(map(lambda x: x*n, lst))
c
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 3, 1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [64]: [list(map(lambda x: x*n, z)) for z in lst]
Out[64]: [[4, 6, 8, 10, 10], [2, 6]]
```

---

То что вы пытаетесь сделать - это умножение списка на целое число:

```
In [67]: [1,2,3] * 2
Out[67]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

В Python при умножении списка на целое `N` получаем список повторенный `N` раз